# Account restricted to google Classroom API

Tags: wpf, google-apis-explorer, google-classroom, google-workspace

My collague  and I have a C# WPF project, which manage courses in Google Classroom.
We create the project in Google API platform. We are the owner of the project.
Both have OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. (but it doesn't matter)
I allow all of Classroom API's scope.

I am the domain admin of our Gsuite for Education. Google Classroom API is allowed in the domain.

He can login and use the program, there is not any error, every function is ok.
I can't, because i got an error 400,  invalid_request Account restricted.

I try with API Explorer, and this error occurs only when I would like to get the list of topics of a google classroom course.

Scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly openid

```
        txtLog.Text += "Try login to Google...\n"; 
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new string[] 
                { 
                    ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomCourses, 
                    ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomRosters, 
                    ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomProfileEmails, 
                    ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomProfilePhotos,
                    ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomTopics
                },
                "admin",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            txtLog.Text += $"Credential file saved to: {credPath}\n";
        }

        // Create Classroom API service.
        service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Jedlik Classroom Manager",
        });

        // Define request parameters.
        CoursesResource.ListRequest request = service.Courses.List();
        request.PageSize = 100;

        // List courses.
        ListCoursesResponse response = request.Execute();
        if (response.Courses != null && response.Courses.Count > 0)
        {
            txtLog.Text +=$"Number of coureses: {response.Courses.Count}\n";
            lstCourses.ItemsSource = response.Courses.ToList();
            lstCourses.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            lstCourses.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
            lstCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        { 
            txtLog.Text += $"No courses found\n";
        }
```

Comment: This might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870551

Comment: Are you designated a teacher of that specific class? It's not enough to be of just the group

Comment: Also owner =/= teacher

Comment: Ok, I try this idea.

Comment: How long does it take to change? Now i change group owner and i add me as teacher. But in the classroom i cant change from owner to teacher.

Comment: Immediately. If this isn't working, please share a sanitised copy of your code.

Comment: Please add the code to your question, rather than leaving it as an answer.

Comment: Try using the 'Try this API' function on [this page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics) and see if you get the same result

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x7uOXuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This sounds like a problem with your account. To get a resolution you should contact G Suite support.*

#### More Information:

If there is an account restriction on the account trying to authenticate then this isn't something that the Stack Overflow community can help with - especially if the same code works for another teacher on your domain ***and*** that you are receiving the same response in the `Try this API` function on the [`courses.topics`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics) reference page.

You can contact G Suite Support using the links on [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

#### Update 2020.06.01:

This actually appears to be a bug!

There is a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Requesting the courses.topics scope gives an error if "Access to additional services without individual control" is set to OFF.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152686011)

Google does seem to know about this issue given the reponses but I figured it would be good to give this an update.

**For future readers:** if this hasn't yet been fixed you can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned issue page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

#### References:

- [Google Classroom API - Method `courses.topics`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics)
- [Contact G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)