# Classroom Topics API is giving me Account Restricted error

Tags: google-classroom

I'm trying to create a topic inside a course using the Classrom API. All other scopes (creating courses, adding teachers, adding students) work just fine. Only the Topics scope is giving me that error. Before anyone asks I am a teacher inside the course I'm trying to create the topic into.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnX7R.jpg)

Comment: Hello, this question seems to have an accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60931003

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Account restricted to google Classroom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929810/account-restricted-to-google-classroom-api)

Comment: I've seen both of those answers and neither apply to me.

Comment: What do you mean by they don't apply? If your user is restricted it means you should contact the administrator.

Comment: I have just found the fix for this issue and it had nothing to do with account restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the issue. The Classroom Topics scope is, for some odd reason, not part of the Classroom service on GSuite. For that you have to enable "Access to additional services without individual control" inside the Admin Console. After I enabled it the scope started working as intended.

Here is the link where I found the answer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152686011